# How to call a child component menthod from parent if the child component is not being called yet?

Tags: typescript, components, angular6, parent-child, angular8

I have a parent component and a child component to add and update tile using a popum component, now add button happen to be in parent component and update is in child component.
when there is no tiles(child component markup) to show, i have to add a tile that time i'm not able to call the child component's method openAddOrUpdatePopup().

How can i call this method in parent component without being depending on child component ?

My code: - 
parent-html

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Add" (click)="applicationTile.openAddOrUpdatePopup()" />
<application-tile class="grid-item action-grid-item enable-events" *ngFor="let application of paginationParams.data" [ngClass]="{'active':activeApplication && activeApplication.applicationId == application.applicationId}" [application]="application"></application-tile>
```

parent.ts

```
export class ApplicationsComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild (ApplicationTileComponent, {static: false}) applicationTile: ApplicationTileComponent ; 
}
```

Child.html

```
<label class="name">{{application.applicationName}}</label>
<div class="table-view">

<div class="table-view-row">
    <div>
        <label>Application value </label>
        <span>{{application.value ? application.value  : '-'}}</span>
    </div>
        <label>Application Version</label>
        <span>{{application.appVersion ? application.appVersion : '-'}}</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li>
            <span class="icon svg-icon action-icon edit-icon" title="Edit" 
 (click)="openAddOrUpdatePopup(application, $event)"></span>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

```
<av-popup class="medium-popup" *ngIf="popupParams && popupParams.name == 'create-or-update-application'" [popupParams]="popupParams" (close)="popupParams = null">
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && popupParams.saveOrUpdateApplication()" #f="ngForm"></form></av-popup>
```

child.ts

```
 openAddOrUpdatePopup(application?, $event?) {
       if (application) {
        application = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(application));
       }
       else {
        application = {
        applicationType: this.applicationTypes[0].applicationTypeVal
       }
     }

this.popupParams = {
  name: 'create-or-update-application',
  title: application.applicationId ? 'Edit ' + application.applicationName : "Create New Application",
  application: application
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate the question bit more? OR can you post the working code in Stackblitz and provide the link?

There are few ways to connect with Parent & child component by using,

Input & Output.

Shared service with Observer (Publish & subscribe)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yycmhu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild-tile%2Fchild-tile.component.html

Comment: Please check the link, the problem is i want to click the add button function even when the applications variable is not set, because the intention is to create the tile with add button but the function is in the child-tile component

Comment: I understand your requirements.. I m in office.. let me work on it after sometime. Thanks..